# Choosing the clock for STM32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, clock

I'm building a custom board using a STM32F303K8T6. This custom board will be connected to 4 other custom boards via CAN bus protocol. The task of the following board is to drive high switches if there is an incoming CAN bus command.

In addition to this I will mount a temperature sensor (perhaps I2C I still have to evaluate) and the value will always be transmitted via CAN bus.
The high switch activation data and the current read by these travel via the CAN bus.

I'm starting to create the schematic but I have a couple of doubts about using or not the external clock. In your opinion, for what I have to do, can I use the internal clock of the STM32 (on the datasheet it says that it is 1% accurate at about 25 degrees)?

Furthermore, the typical value written on the datasheet is 8 MHz but the Nucleo board mounts a 32 MHz one.

I specify that I come from the Arduino / ESP world and I decided to take the path towards STM32. I've never understood how to choose the clock. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't use the STM32F onboard clock to do this in any reliable way. The base tolerance is already +/-1%, which means that across two nodes you could have more than 2% relative error straight out of the box. This will cause problems with CAN communications. Further, the temperature stability is poor and this can push the relative error out by at least another 1%.

For reliable CAN communications your best bet is to just use a ceramic resonator. These are dirt cheap, low power and simple to use. Something with a +/-0.5% tolerance will be adequate as the CAN specification allows for up to 1.58% of relative timing error between nodes, but check the situation at whatever temperature extremes you want to operate at as well.

Also note that the limit on CAN timing tolerance is to allow a node to distinguish between a local and bus-wide error condition. But this only comes into play when an error occurs, so the bus will happily receive messages at higher timing error levels. But you'll now have created a 'hidden' problem on the bus that might result in random weird node drop outs that take ages to debug. This is why it's best to just be very conservative with CAN implementations - they are very fault tolerant, but don't allow this to lull you into a sloppy implementation.

Also note that the new STM32G devices have a more accurate clock that is theoretically able to meet the CAN requirements across a limited temperature range (roughly commercial grade if I recall correctly). These could work but you'd be putting a lot of faith in ST's quality control. I'd still opt for an external resonator unless you're seriously trying to squeeze cost (and can do your own oscillator characterisation testing).

Comment: Ok so the solution is definitely an external crystal. On the datasheet the value should typically be set from 8mhz to max 32mhz. Can I put an external 8 crystal? I had found this: ABM3B-8.000MHZ-10-1-U-T , which has a tolerance of 10ppm. The baudrate I thought to use the 250kbs. I forgot to mention that the cards will be mounted on a prototype car (not on the road).

Answer (score 2):

The absolute minimum accuracy required for CAN is 1.58%. However, I strongly recommend to keep it below 1%. It depends on what baudrate you intend to use, the higher the baudrate, the more accurate the clock needs to be.

Furthermore you need to provide the CAN peripheral with a clock that is suitable for prescaling, so that it can configure the location of the sample point accurately.

See [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251) The recommendation to avoid RC oscillators or ceramic resonators when doing 250kbps or faster is from the CAN standard. The best option is very likely to use external quartz and then follow ST's recommendations regarding layout and component values.

Unrelated to CAN, you should check if flash wait states are required when passing a certain system clock. If so you need to configure some flash register before enabling a fast running oscillator.

Comment: Ok so the solution is definitely an external crystal. On the datasheet the value should typically be set from 8mhz to max 32mhz. Can I put an external 8 crystal? I had found this: ABM3B-8.000MHZ-10-1-U-T , which has a tolerance of 10ppm. The baudrate I thought to use the 250kbs. I forgot to mention that the cards will be mounted on a prototype car (not on the road).

Comment: @Nik_01 I don't know how this specific part works in regards to clocks and built-in oscillators. It might be able to take an 8MHz crystal and generate a multiple of that frequency for system clock.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, always compare the precision of available clock sources to the precision you need. These are usually mentioned in MCU documentation as well, but as you use CAN the precision requirement or tolerance for the bit rate will be in CAN specs. Also take the tolerance into account within the temperature and supply voltage range you intend to use the MCU. The tolerance of internal oscillators might be adverized to be 1% but it is 1% only at certain temperature and supply. For the STM32F303, tolerance goes up to 2% between range of 0 to 55 degrees C, and since your product is used in a car, expect temperature changes beyond that.

The optimal crystal frequency is much more complex question, as it might always be a compromise. These are always mentioned in data sheets, reference manuals, and application notes.

Your MCU supports crystals in the range of 4 to 32 MHz and external oscillators in the 1 to 32 MHz range, with typical of 8 MHz. That's a good reason to just pick 8 MHz as that is typical and same as the internal oscillator frequency.

Frequency-wise, the frequency does not matter much, as the MCU can run directly at the input frequency, or up to 72 MHz, which can be achieved with the internal PLL. From the input frequency, higher and lower frequencies can be generated with the PLL.

So for the PLL, the PLL can accept frequencies between 1 and 24 MHz, and the PLL can output between 16 and 72 MHz. It can have a pre-divider, a multiplier, and a post-divider. All limits for the frequencies at each stage must be obeyed, but fortunately these calculations can simply be left for manufacturer tools to configure as they see fit. The data sheet and reference manual has details on this.

For the oscillator and crystal, the higher frequency you use, the stricter are the crystal parameters that lead to reliable operation. There is also an app note on crystal selection. The basic idea is, to have the same margin of reliability in all conditions, higher frequencies require lower ESR and lower load capacitance, and this again makes the changes in stray capacitances affect the oscillating frequency more that at higher load capacitances. It is also harder and more expensive to find a suitable high frequency crystal, but on the other hand, higher frequency can be available in smaller packages.

If going for lower frequency crystals, they have more margin for stable operation, they are easier to find and allow for more load capacitance and changes in load capacitance due to stray capacitances has less effect on frequency. They also come in larger packages physically. But of course too low frequencies can't be used with the built-in oscillator, and there is always a sweet spot for the PLL input, which for some other STM32 chips is as low as between 1 and 2 MHz.

So the typical 8 MHz is a good compromise for all aspects, not too high, not too low. It is also a common multiple for generating the maximum frequency and 48 MHz for USB if needed. It is also listed as supported frequency for the system boot loader as it does not support any arbitrary frequencies. Some system boot loaders have some limitations and work better at lower than high frequencies. See the appnote for system boot modes for more info.

If smaller, cheaper, and slightly less precise option is tolerated for low speed CAN, there are ceramic resonators that can be used instead of crystals, but high speed CAN requires a crystal, even according to specs.

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer. I found an 8Mhz crystal with 10ppm tolerance, load capacity: 10pf and ESR of 200ohm. (ABM3B-8.000MHZ-10-1UT). The only point that I don't know if it can fit is the ESR since it's quite "big". While on the can side I've usually heard of the mc2551s but they are now obsolete for new applications. For this I thought to use MCP2562FD. @Justme

Comment: @Nik_01 You can read the crystal selection appnote to learn how to find out if the crystal is suitable or not. 10ppm may be unnecessarily good and thus more expensive than what you need. Which CAN PHY chip you will use does not relate to choosing a crystal though.